# Looking to display picture on upload in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to use :hint when uploading a picture to display it immediately in the form. I just discovered the function, but do not seem to be using it properly as I get an error.
I was looking to replace the following

```
<div class="input-group " style="width: 100% !important;">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-inverse" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">Browse</span>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar, onchange: "$(this).parent().parent().find('.form-control').html($(this).val().split(/[\\\\|/]/).pop());", style: "display: none;" %>
    </span>
    <span class="form-control"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
```

Within the following form, using :hint

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {method: :put, multipart: true}) do |f| %>
     <%= f.error_notification %>
     <% if @user.avatar? %>
       <%= avatar_for(@user) %>
     <% else %>
       <%= image_tag("Avatar_default.jpg", alt: "No profile picture", width: "100%") %>
     <% end %>
     <br>
     <%=  f.input :avatar, :as => :file, :hint => image_tag(f.object.avatar.url) %>
     <%=  f.input :avatar_cache, :as => :hidden  %>
     <%= f.button :submit, "Update", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Ideally I would like to have a browse file button, select the image, then see a preview in the image as the user continues to fill in the form.

I am certainly not filling the following right: `image_tag(f.object.avatar.url)`

Comment: Hey Etienne, try to use http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/ we are successfully using it on our rails app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommends you to do it with a javascript/jquery help:

```
function showImage(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#your_preview_id')
          .attr('src', e.target.result)
          .width(150)
          .height(200);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

This code gets the image from yout input and inserts it inside the `#your_preview_id` element, but, for to id, you need to do the following:

```
<%= f.input :avatar, :as => :file, id: "image_upload_id" %>
<%= f.button :submit, "Update", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Giving this id to your input, bind the change for him, and do the following:

```
$('#image_upload_id').on('change', function() {
    showImage(this);
})
```

Don't forget to create a landing place for your image preview:

```
<div id="your_preview_id"></div>
```

Comment: It actually didn't work with the <div>, i had to used <img> to get it working for me.